# Heroku bundle: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a Rails/ReactJS app on Heroku, and I've committed and pushed the app onto it. However, when I try to run any `rake` command, or `bundler --version` on the Heroku CLI, I get the following error:

`bash: bundler: command not found`

I've tried the following to no avail.

```
$ heroku config:set GEM_PATH=vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.1
$ heroku config:set PATH=bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

I'm on Ruby 3.1.1. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Is the Heroku app using the "heroku/ruby" buildpack? (The "Buildpack" section of the "Settings" tab of the Heroku app). I think this automatically is set if first deployed with a `Gemfile`, but maybe your app wasn't. Since it's also a React app, you probably need the "heroku/nodejs" buildpack, too.

Comment: @Unixmonkey Hi! Yes, it's using both buildpacks (ruby and nodejs).